# udevadm looks wrong after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, lubuntu

After upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 my usb keyboard and mouse need to be reconnected after starting up my laptop. Startup time increased significantly as well, at least 3 times.

Kernel: `5.4.0-48-generic` 
On `systemctl` I can see that

> systemd-udev-trigger.service loaded failed  failed    udev Coldplug all Devices

I checked and /sbin/udevadm looks like that:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> if [ "${0##*/}" = "udevtrigger" ] || [ "$1" = "trigger" ]; then
> echo "udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured." 1>&2
> exit 1 fi
>
> if [ "${0##*/}" = "udevsettle" ] || [ "$1" = "settle" ]; then
> echo "udevadm settle is not permitted while udev is unconfigured." 1>&2
> exit 1 fi
>
> exec /bin/bash -c "exec -a "$0" /sbin/udevadm.upgrade "$@"" "$0"
> "$@"

which doesn't look ok from what I found.

In /var/lib/dpkg/status I found:

```
Package: udev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: important
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 9113
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: systemd
Version: 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
```

Attempt to start this service manually results in:

```
@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status systemd-udev-trigger.service
systemd-udev-trigger.service - udev Coldplug all Devices
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udev-trigger.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-08 20:29:46 CEST; 4h 30min ago
       Docs: man:udev(7)
             man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
    Process: 416 ExecStart=/sbin/udevadm trigger --type=subsystems --action=add (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 416 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

20:29:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
20:29:46 ubuntu udevadm[416]: udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured.
20:29:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
20:29:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
20:29:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start udev Coldplug all Devices.
```

I tried reinstalling and updating udev, it succeeds but doesn't resolve the issue. I tried a bunch of available tips on how to fix broken packages like:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and similar, but no luck. If it can be found on first 3 google search pages - I already tried it.

What would be the solution to my problem, except for reinstalling the whole system? Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged Lubuntu, and mention upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. Lubuntu 18.04 was the last release using LXDE and thus the releases notes for later releases (eg. https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) "*due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" as issues should have been  expected. I would test current *live* media (eg. Lubuntu 20.04.1) to confirm

Comment: This can also happen to headless installations without LXDE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637267/udev-is-unconfigured-how-to-debug